# How to measure Apache Flume EPS?

Tags: performance, benchmarking, flume, eps

I'm beginning with Flume-NG, and for initial hardware setup I want to measure Flume's performance(EPS) on existing test machine with linux.

Just an agent with simple 'Syslog to Hbase' flow is running in the machine and I know how to inject heavy load to the Flume Source end.

What I don't have any idea is:

- Which point in the flow my measurement should place.
- How to measure EPS with which tool.
- Any premises which might be necessary.

I've made a lot of Googling with several key words but nothing came out, just some benchmarking result with EPS found.

Please be kind understand that my question may not be so clear enough because I have completely no experience on this kind of server work.

Your adding comments, I'll try to explain what you don't understand about my question, or what I don't understand from your comment.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You could monitor flume-ng with JMX. To enable JMX in /bin/flume-ng change the JAVA_OPTS like below:

JAVA_OPTS="-Xms100m -Xmx200m -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.10.10.10 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=6543 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"

flume-ng as very detailed jmx metrics for source/channel/sink. Once JMX is enabled you could use jconsole/jvisualvm ...

Comment: Thanks for your advise. Mean while I also came to know that Flume provides metrics reporting via HTTP, Ganglia and JMX etc and I tried the HTTP way in order to see what kinds of metrics it reports, but it doesn't not report rate related info such as EPM but only accumulated counting stuff such as 'event count conveyed so far'. Anyway let me try the JMX way as well because it may report additional info differently from the HTTP.